# Scaling viewports in Godot 3

Tags: game-engine, viewport, pixel, scaling, godot

New to Godot/GDScript and I am making a pixel art game.

Low res graphics can easily be scaled up by scaling the viewport, however this affects the scale of all the nodes in the tree. Scaling down the viewport give the desirable crisp edges **which cant be gotten from scaling up a sprite** node (otherwise the pixel art blurs). The problem comes in when I want to display text or GUI elements over the game.

I want to:

1. render a tilemap and game sprites on a scaled up node/viewport e.g 120x100 scaled to the window size
2. Render buttons and text (hud) at a consistent higher resolution on top of the game without scaling

I have tried playing multiple viewports but I just dont have a grasp it yet.

Any help in setting this up would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think the setup for this could look like this:

```
- scene
  - GameViewportContainer
    - Viewport
  - UIViewportContainer
    - Viewport
```

With the ViewportContainers stretch set to true.

Then in a script on GameViewportContainer:

```
extends ViewportContainer

var your_custom_size = Vector2(128, 128)

func _ready():
    $Viewport.connect('size_changed', self, '_on_viewport_size_changed')
    change_viewport_size()

func _on_viewport_size_changed():
    change_viewport_size()

func change_viewport_size():
    $Viewport.set_size_override(true, your_custom_size)
    $Viewport.set_size_override_stretch(true)
```

For further reading checkout:

1. https://godotengine.org/qa/25504/pixel-perfect-scaling
2. https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/6506

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `$ViewportContainer/Viewport` node is not a node in the code you provided. I substituted those nodes with `$Viewport`. I then added a tileMap as child to the Viewport in the GameViewportContainer but there is nothing to see - the child doesnt even show.

Comment: I got the child to appear by setting the viewport container size to that of the window.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that is a typo. Edited.

Comment: Viewports are finicky in the editor. I recommend creating another scene and editing it there then instance that scene under the viewport.

Comment: Another thing, I think the UIViewportContainer subtree isn't needed at all. You can just use godot's viewport editor settings to configure that. Unless if that messes with the GameViewportContainer subtree.